# Matplotlib x axis day of year to datetime formating

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib figure showing the max and min temps of each day from a few years worth of data. My current xaxis is the index of this data, so 365 data points. I want to change this to where the months are displayed on the x axis rather than the index.

What are some ways I can do this?

The following is my code from the plotting cell of my jupyter notebook.
"""

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
plt.xlabel('Day of Year', fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('Temperature (℃)', fontsize=20)


plt.title('Ten Year Record (2005-2014) Near Ann Arbor, Michigan', fontsize=25) 
plt.plot(max_04to15.values, c = 'red', label ='Record High')
plt.plot(min_04to15.values, c = 'blue', label ='Record Low')
#plt.plot(mean_04to15.values, c = 'black', label = 'Average Temp')

plt.scatter(break_max.index.tolist(), break_max['Data_Value_y'].values, marker = "^", c = 'black', label = "Broken High in 2015")
plt.scatter(break_min.index.tolist(), break_min['Data_Value_y'].values, marker = "v", c = 'orange', label = "Broken Low in 2015")


plt.gca().fill_between(range(len(max_04to15)), 
                       np.array(max_04to15.values.reshape(len(min_04to15.values),)), 
                       np.array(min_04to15.values.reshape(len(min_04to15.values),)), 
                       facecolor='#2F99B4', 
                       alpha=0.25)

plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.legend(loc = 'best', fontsize=18, frameon = False)
plt.show()
```

"""

Comment: Consider using Plotly for plotting. This takes care of date strings and ensure clean spacing.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can make arrays of datetime with numpy:

```
ax.fill_between(np.arange('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]'), 
                       upper, lower, facecolor='#2F99B4', alpha=0.25)
```